# UIMA Ruta : script for the combination of chars and numbers

Tags: ruta

I've just started with Ruta and I would like to write a rule that finds any combination of chars, numbers and dot (.) .

(JAVA Regex for it - ([a-z0-9.]+) )

for e.g. -

abcd.03ef0.3abc

03a.bcd.03eeff903a.bc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following:

```
(SW | NUM | PERIOD)+{-> MyType};
```

or if uppercase chars should also be included:

```
(W | NUM | PERIOD)+{-> MyType};
```

change the filtering setting before, if no spaces may occur in between:

```
Document{-> RETAINTYPE(SPACE,BREAK,MARKUP)};
```

in order to avoid overlapping matches, you can either use MARKONCE instead of the implicit action, an additional (negated) condition -PARTOF(MyType), or change the matching strategy with GREEDYANCHORING.

Answer (score 0):

I have been watching this question for some time. I also have question similar to this.

My problem is to match large number separated by commas like:
123,343,223

I have written rules similar to the answer but it yields too many matches:

```
123,343,223
123,343
343,223
....
```

My rule is something like:

```
(NUM COMMA)+ {-> LargeNum} NUM;
```

It just can't exactly match what I want to match, ie. 123,343,223. The problem is the quantifier. You need quantifier in order to apply the same rules repeatedly. But the consequence is it yields more matches than desired.

Clearly, it needs further filtering.

Comment: Can you give an example for a false positive match? I just assume that you get additional matched for the inner combinations. You could try to use MARKONCE, or add -PARTOF(LargeNum) at the first NUM. You could also use GREEDYANCHORING (UIMA Ruta >=2.2.1). I don't know if that is your problem. Can you create a new question for this problem?

Comment: btw, the action of your rule does not cover the last rule element. Maybe try something like the following: ((NUM COMMA)+ NUM){-> MARKONCE(LargeNum)} ;

Comment: Ah...thank you. Your last comment is the correct answer. I haven't tried ((NUM COMMA)+ NUM) before. I have tried many combinations before but lack the intuition to try this pattern. The UIMA Ruta tutorial is just too short.

Comment: Those matches I don't want should be the inner combinations, rather than false positive match. Thank you.